# LVL is not available in the eclipse repository

Tags: android, eclipse, android-lvl

I tried to download the Google APIs Add-on, to be able to use the LVL system on my android emulator.

However, it seems that the Google APIs Add-on are not available on my eclipse in the Available packages list.

Any ideas ?

Screenshot of my eclipse
[image]

Screenshot of what I should get (image from http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#ServerManagedPolicy)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is already installed (You have "display updates only" selected).

Also, you should update your ADT plugin. The screens do not look like that any more and the new ones are much easier to use.